# Level generator 3d endless runner

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, unityscript

[Code for level generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EACgQ.png) [This is how and where the level's spawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iszZX.png)I'm trying to instantiate my segments which are my levels in my endless runner game, it works, the levels spawn, but unfortunately they do not spawn in the place i want them to. For example it will spawn sometimes above the game and i want them to spawn next to each other if that makes sense.

What i did i created a coroutine that spawns my levels that are called segments that are stored within an array and they instantiate every 2 seconds, Idk if the problem is because my segments aren't the same size...

Comment: are all your prefabs pivoting on 0,0,0 ?

Comment: If they are of different sizes, you should expose a value on the prefab (or use collider size if applicable), and use that value when increasing the spawn pos.

Comment: no they at first they spawn on top of my other segments then spawn in other places if that makes sense.

Comment: check the pivots on the prefabs, as suggested by @BugFinder.  Its likely the pivot is not where it should be or where you expect it to be

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm new to unity, and coding in general. What do you mean by check the pivot. Can i move it? @hijinxbassist

Comment: If your model(s) are parented under an empty gameobject, that gameobject is essentially the pivot point.  If that gameobject is centered relative to the child objects, then the faux pivot is centered.  There is a toggle button at the top of the editor that is either "Center" or "Pivot", toggle that to compare the pivot to the center of the renderer(s) bounds.  When placing objects using transform.position, you are moving the object based on that pivot.  A pivot can be anywhere relative to the meshes, and leads to issues like shown above.